# What's the right way to configure a one-to-one relationship when using Entity Framework Core migrations so that foreign keys are added to both tables?

Tags: entity-framework-core, entity-framework-migrations, ef-fluent-api

Let's say I have two entities/model class

**AccountModel**:

```cs
    public class AccountModel
    {
        [Key]
        public int AccountSk { get; set; }

        [ForeignKey("Region")]
        public int RegionSk { get; set; }

        public virtual RegionModel Region { get; set; } = new RegionModel();
    }
```

**RegionModel**:

```cs
    [Table("Region")]
    public class RegionModel
    {
        [Key]
        public int RegionSk { get; set; }

        [ForeignKey("Account")]
        public int AccountSk { get; set; }

        public virtual AccountModel Account { get; set; } = new AccountModel();
    }
```

And I configure them this way inside my DbContext class inside the `OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder builder)` method

```cs
        builder.Entity<RegionModel>()
            .HasOne(region => region.Account)
            .WithOne(account => account.Region);

        builder.Entity<AccountModel>()
            .HasOne(account => account.Region)
            .WithOne(region => region.Account);
```

When I run `Add-Migration [MyMigrationName]` in the Package Manager Console, it only adds the foreign key to whichever model class's relationship I have configured first inside `OnModelCreating`. In this case, the **Region** table will get its column **AccountSk** correctly created as a foreign key but **Account** table will not get any foreign keys created... like this:

```cs
            migrationBuilder.CreateTable(
                name: "Account",
                columns: table => new
                {
                    AccountSk = table.Column<int>(type: "int", nullable: false)
                        .Annotation("SqlServer:Identity", "1, 1"),
                    RegionSk = table.Column<int>(type: "int", nullable: false)
                },
                constraints: table =>
                {
                    table.PrimaryKey("PK_Account", x => x.AccountSk);
                });

            migrationBuilder.CreateTable(
                name: "Region",
                columns: table => new
                {
                    RegionSk = table.Column<int>(type: "int", nullable: false),
                    AccountSk = table.Column<int>(type: "int", nullable: false)
                },
                constraints: table =>
                {
                    table.PrimaryKey("PK_Region", x => x.RegionSk);
                    table.ForeignKey(
                        name: "FK_Region_Account_RegionSk",
                        column: x => x.RegionSk,
                        principalTable: "Account",
                        principalColumn: "AccountSk",
                        onDelete: ReferentialAction.Cascade);
                });
```

I have double checked that switching the order of the configuration inside `OnModelCreating` for these two tables with a one-to-one relationship causes the opposite issue (Account table getting a correct foreign key and Region table not).

What is the correct way to configure this one-to-one relationship for both tables so that they both get foreign keys created?

TL;DR
I am trying to have two tables created, `Account` and `Region` that have a one-to-one relationship with each other. I am trying to do this using Entity Framework Core migrations using Fluent API in my .NET Core application.

`Account` has a primary key `AccountSk` and `Region` has a primary key `RegionSk`.

`Account` has a foreign key `RegionSk` that references the primary key of `Region`.
`Region` has a foreign key `AccountSk` that references the primary key of `Account'.

Comment: One-to-one never has FKs in both tables. You probably are mixing navigation properties with FKs. FK is always in one of the tables called dependent. See https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/modeling/relationships?tabs=fluent-api%2Cfluent-api-simple-key%2Csimple-key#one-to-one

Comment: Yeah I just tried updating the automatically created Migration code to add the foreign key to the table without it and I felt pretty dumb haha. Thank you for your answer though, I think I did get that mixed up or something.